# Zephyr Squad Server: Import test results without creating new Jira tickets

Tags: cucumber, jira, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, jira-zephyr

We're using Zephyr Squad Server.

---

TLDR:

Is there a solution to import automatic test results (as bulk) into Zephyr Squad Server, without creating new Jira Tickets (solely add new test execution to old Test ticket).

---

Our goal is to import the results from your automatic E2E tests into Zephyr.
These E2Es are execute by Cypress with the Cucumber Plugin.

Result-Files are available in junit.xml and cucumber.json.

I'm able to update the test execution status of a single test in a test cycle via the Zephyr API. But this is kinda cumbersome (extract Jira-Test-Id from cucumber.json, find the newest test execution, find the test execution id, bla bla..., way to much REST calls).

So my other idea was to use the "test automation task" and upload a single junit.xml to Zephyr.

The problem here is that this import will always create a new Jira Test Ticket. So we lose the ability to keep track about the test execution of a particular test over several versions.

I checked that the naming of the test cases in the junit.xml is exactly like in Jira, but this doesn't help either (unlike with Xray). I find the documentation of Zephyr, especially for the Server variation, is really lacking some details. I'm used to the Xray where it's kinda simple to export cucumber tests and import cucumber results. So maybe I'm just missing something here.

Best regards

Kai